# Browser extension to create independent cookie stores narrower than spec

Tags: firefox, cookies, session, cookiecontainer

Does anyone know of a browser extension (preferably Firefox) that allows you to create independent cookie stores at a finer (and configurable) granularity than the specification?

E.g. say http://a.example.com/ first sends

```
Set-Cookie: a=bar; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-2010 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com
```

So clearly this would also be sent by Firefox for anything subsequently requested under http://b.example.com/ .  I want the extension to *not* send the header for b.example.com.  Typically, this will cause b.example.com to send a different set-cookie header, which would then be resent only for b.example.com.  The idea is to create multiple independent sessions on the same site.

It would be an added bonus if it supported other granularity schemes (e.g. http://example.com/a/ is separate from http://example.com/b/).

This strikes me as somewhat similar to [Applications Boundaries Enforcer](http://noscript.net/abe/), but different and not within its scope (though I could be wrong).

Finally, I'm aware that this could give you enough rope to hang yourself.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar (multiple browser windows with different cookies and settings) with Chrome's [multiple user](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824) feature.

This might be doable with Firefox profiles too, and `-no-remote`.