# Can a browser maintain multiple sessions with one server?

Tags: iphone, browser, session

Is there a way to maintain multiple sessions with one server within the browser?

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:
User1 has exclusive access to ContentA and User2 has exclusive access to ContentB. I want to be able to allow User3 to login multiple times, to allow access to ContentA and ContentB.

I admit that this scenario seems almost silly but it stems from the fact that I can't change the way the server handles content permissions.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish this without touching the server? In say Safari on the iPhone?

Comment: This is the same as my question [Browser extension to create independent cookie stores narrower than spec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152691/browser-extension-to-create-independent-cookie-stores-narrower-than-spec), which has not quite been answered yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible by setting different paths in the Cookies.

```
Set-Cookie: ... ; path=/path/to/contentA; domain=.example.com ...
```

and

```
Set-Cookie: ... ; path=/path/to/contentB; domain=.example.com ...
```

for the other content.

Comment: BTW, I don't know, how you would do that on the iPhone - but generally, if you have any angle to tamper with the stored cookies on the client side, this could work without touching the server.